# making ball to fall from top to bottom when the button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a program to animate the ball when the button is clicked. It is a part of experiment for a bigger project:
Here is the screen shot:
[image: Website]
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HTML5 Random Bouncing Ball</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body { background-color:#ededed; font:normal 12px/18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
h1 { display:block; width:600px; margin:20px auto; padding-bottom:20px; font:normal 24px/30px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#333; text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cbcbcb; }

#myCanvas { background:#fff; border:1px solid #cbcbcb; }
#nav { display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; }
#nav li { display:block; font-weight:bold; line-height:21px; text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff; width:100px; height:21px; padding:5px; margin:0 10px; background:#e0e0e0; border:1px solid #ccc; -moz-border-radius:4px;-webkit-border-radius:4px; border-radius:4px; float:left; }
#nav li a { color:#000; display:block; text-decoration:none; width:100%; height:100%; }
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction () {

        var context;
        var dx= 4;  
        var dy=4;
        var y=150;
        var x=10;
        function draw(){
            context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle="#000000";
            context.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
            if( x<0 || x>400)
            dx=-dx;
            if( y<0 || y>300)
            dy=-dy;
            x+=dx;
            y+=dy;
        }
        setInterval(draw,10); 
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>



</div>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter" onclick="myFunction();"/>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the ball to fall from top to bottom when the button is pressed?

Comment: I'd imagine the lack of details - what issues are you experiencing with the code you have so far?

Comment: I'm not experiencing any lags, it is working fine, however if I click on the ball, it just bounces off the walls. I want it to fall from top to bottom when the button is clicked.

Comment: @SonamBharti I downvoted because you asked how to animate the ball 1minute ago, it looks like you'll make a new question for every step you want in 'your' project. And you can set a default height so it starts from the top, it's not that hard.

Comment: @Nick to be fair, it was another SO member who suggested the OP create a new question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was:

```
function myFunction () {

    var context;
    var dx= 4;  
    var dy=4;
    var y=50;
    var x=10;
    function draw(){
        context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle="#FFBAA3";
        context.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        if( x<0 || x>100)
            dx=-dx;
        if( y<0 || y>300)
            dy=0;
            //x+=dx;
             y+=dy;

    }
    setInterval(draw,10); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps, you need to do, first, disable the vertical speed (you dont need to delete it, just set it to 0), then in the "draw" function delete the if loops, and create a new, like this:

`if (y >= 300) {
    y = 290; // Set the ball's Y position to the bottom of the canvas
    dy = 0; //And finally this set the falling is zero
 }`

And if you want it more complicated, create a new variable, "gravity", and in every turn increase the dy variable with the gravity. Then the code above must to look like this:

`if (y >= 300) {
    y = 290; // Set the ball's Y position to the bottom of the canvas
    dy = 0; //And finally this set the falling is zero
    gravity = 0;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, what you need:

```
 function myFunction () {
            var context;
            var dy=4;  //First: dx must be 0;
            var dx = 0;
            var y=150;
            var x=10;
            function draw(){
                context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
                context.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
                context.beginPath();
                context.fillStyle="#000000";
                context.arc(x,y,10,0,Math.PI*2,true);
                context.closePath();
                context.fill();
                if (y >= 300) {  //Second: delete all if loop and add this
                    y = 290;     //                                     |
                    dy = 0;      //     <-------------------------------|                               
                }
                x+=dx;
                y+=dy;
            }
            setInterval(draw,10); 
    }`
```

EDIT:

And a tip: Press F12 in the browser, and click on the Console (or log under some browsers) and you got all the error message's.

Answer (score -2):

If you want, to the ball fall straight down, then dont give him a vertical movement.

EDIT:

If you need that, the ball dont go off the screen, then simply set the x and y position next to the wall.

Comment: You don't need to use `document.getElementById` if the id is declared and unique.

Comment: See... I don't want any bouncing effects. I want a simple fall from top to bottom